# CakePHP parserror with _serialize for JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cakephp

I have problem with JSON. Can someone tell me why first option works and second no?
Second option is working in every other controller, but not in this one.

In database i have table with name **statuses**, and model in CakePHP - **Status**
Is this somehow relevant to this case?

Here is the error i'm recieving

```
parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
```

My CakePHP controller function option 1 (**working**):

```
       public function admin_add(){

        if($this->request->is('ajax'))
        {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->Status->create();
            if ($this->Status->save($this->request->data)){
                $statuses = $this->Status->findById($this->Status->id);
                $message = "Status has been added";
                $status = "OK";
                //$this->set(compact("message",'status','statuses'));
                //$this->set('_serialize',array('message','status','statuses'));

                echo json_encode(array(
                        'statuses' => $statuses,
                        'message' =>$message,
                        'status' => $status
                    ));
            }
        } 
    }
```

And second **NOT working**:
public function admin_add(){

```
        if($this->request->is('ajax'))
        {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->Status->create();
            if ($this->Status->save($this->request->data)){
                $statuses = $this->Status->findById($this->Status->id);
                $message = "Status has been added";
                $status = "OK";

                $this->set(compact("message",'status','statuses'));
                $this->set('_serialize',array('message','status','statuses'));

                /*echo json_encode(array(
                        'statuses' => $statuses,
                        'message' =>$message,
                        'status' => $status
                    ));*/
            }
        } 
    }
```

And my ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url : location.pathname+"/add",
  data: data,
  dataType: "json",
  success : function(resp){ //some actions here }
```

I have no idea why standard set('_serialize, ...) method isn't working properly :(

Comment: Defining _serialize as an array has the added benefit of automatically appending a top-level <response> element when using XmlView. If you use a string value for _serialize and XmlView, make sure that your view variable has a single top-level element. Without a single top-level element the Xml will fail to generate. -Probably cause it returns something else(xml)

Comment: It is also important to call the url with json extension: action.json - otherwise your serialize approach will fail. And you don't leverage the full potential of the rest responsiveness of cake.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea why standard set('_serialize, ...) method isn't working
>   properly :(

But I have: Did you add the RequestHandlerComponent in yor AppController?

You don't have to call

```
  $this->autoRender = false;
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
```

This as well, the RequestHandler will take care of it.

Comment: I do have RequestHandler, _serialize works in other controllers but not in this one.

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of CakePHP.  I had this problem with version 2.4.2 and fixed it by upgrading to 2.4.3.